# PopUp de Impressão Interferindo no Documento Principal

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Estou utilizando um plugin para fazer impressão de determinada página.

É o **jQueryPrintElement.js**.
http://projects.erikzaadi.com/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement/

Quando clico no botão para fazer a impressão, abre o popup (do Chrome, por exemplo) para clicar em imprimir. Como se fosse o CTRL + P.

Mas se eu clico em cancelar a impressão, ele volta para minha tela, mas ele altera o estilo de alguns elementos da página! Vejo isso pelo Inspect Element. Fiz o teste, abri o popup, cliquei em cancelar e alterou a página.

Como isso acontece ?

Comment: Ele provavelmente adiciona uma classe no body ou outro elemento para ficar bonito na impressão e depois não retira. Mas sem ver o código ou um exemplo do problema ao vivo vai ser muito difícil ajudar.

Comment: http://www.contosdatiasil.com.br/jogos/colorir. Veja Sérgio. Clica num desenho, clica no botão imprimir e depois cancele e depois clique no botão voltar. Você verá as miniaturas do desenho... isso acontece depois que clico em Imprimir e Cancelar.

Comment: Há algum plugin que está a fazer [estas mudanças](https://www.diffchecker.com/fpzdy4sg), agora é perceber qual deles... Podes recriar esse problema no jsFiddle? Se não vais ter de ir 1 a 1 eleminando o script e ver quando isso para. Começa com o plugin do caroussel e print. Se fizeres um jsFiddle dá para ajudar mais.

Comment: São exatamente essas, mais especificamente as que acontecem no **carousel** das miniaturas.

Comment: Por que a negativação numa pergunta de 3 meses atrás ?

Comment: Hmm... não acho que seja caso de negativar, mas pessoas diferentes pensam diferente. `+1` para igualar :)

Comment: @Sergio, eu não me importo com pontuação, o que eu achei estranho é a pergunta ser de 3 meses atrás. Acho que foi o usuário Comunidade para darem atenção a pergunta. Esse usuário faz isso ? De qualquer maneira, obrigado. Minha vó está em Portugal nesse momento.

Comment: O utilizador Comunidade não vota negativo sozinho. E também não dá para saber quem votou. Enfim, fica a zeros pelo menos. Podias abrir um "issue" lá no github com o problema que descreves a ver se te ajudam e depois postas aqui a solução :P

Comment: Eu resolvi essa questão, mas não postei aqui. :b

Comment: haha, então foi a tua consciência a votar `-1` para te lembrar de responder e partlhar conhecimento :) Diz quando responderes que dou uma olhada na resposta.

Comment: Certo. Vou entrar no código depois e buscar a resolução. Rsrs